# Just a thought- If I acquire a Gold Badge through consecutively logging in for 100 days ~ will my answers for my questions be more elaborate?

Tags: discussion, badges, consecutive-days

Should I log in for 100 consecutive for all my StackExchange Accounts?

Will this make me seem more mature and give me a higher quality of answers?

Comment: *can't... resist* Try it and see.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Hm, this sounds like something that should be discussed in therapy, not on Meta... That said, for some of us, Meta _is_ therapy...

Comment: If someone's answer is affected by what's in your user profile section, you probably don't want them posting an answer to your question to begin with.

Comment: I think by the time somebody reaches your user card. They will already have an opinion on the post. Good or bad.

Comment: [Someone](http://stackexchange.com/users/145766/yibe?tab=accounts) has already done this. The badge is to assume that visiting a site daily will get you reading and contributing. I highly doubt this changes the contents/quality of your post.

Comment: Would having gold coloured source code make the website any better? A question being good or bad is surely defined by the content - good grammar, well presented code, clear question. Your badges might have some influence on people's approach to it, whether positive or negative would depend on the person viewing it. The most likely influence would be if you have gold badges and high rep and posted a poor question - people would expect more.

Comment: Low-Rep user with golden badges looks a bit funny. It's like riding on the battle horse with club and wicker buckler.

Comment: @DaveChen -- please tell me they wrote a script to visit each site once a day, instead of manually visiting each and every SE site.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? Its a honest question, and it follows the guidelines.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are looking to earn badges *only* to lure in more elaborate answers, your plan may backfire horribly.

Having a couple (or more) gold badges makes you look like a more experienced member, and answerers *may* be less forgiving with any issues your questions might have. Obviously I'm only speaking for myself here, but I wouldn't really waste any time commenting on a crap question if I thought the asker was a veteran user. I'd just downvote and move on, got much better things to do with my time. It'd be a whole different story if I thought the asker was a newer user (I'd probably still downvote - I'm an ass - but I'd also comment and edit).

Badges are cool, but not *really* significant. It's always nice when you get one (especially a gold one), but if you spend more than a couple of seconds thinking about it, you are doing it wrong. Concentrate on familiarizing yourself with the community and providing interesting questions and helpful answers, and it won't be long before you earn a ton of badges and reputation points.

Comment: I've found that it's more than badges and reputation points... it actually helps you become better at whatever you're answering. If you're not Eric Lippert you sometimes have to go and research the docs where you can always learn something different or someone comes up with a better method or maybe there's another language involved that you don't use but you learn something about. I'm "active" on Stack Overflow because I'm addicted but I became addicted because I realised how much I was learning from this place.

Comment: I bet Eric Lippert looks stuff up before/while he posts an answer. But yes, of course, the gamification aspects are only for fun. The real trick is that you're helping other people out while you're helping yourself.

Comment: @Yannis There is a diffrence between being leniant/being respectful towards another member. Your perspective on a beginner compared to a person who looks like a veteran obviously is diffrent. Although so to speak the greatest respect comes to friends/popular members it still cultivates itself through medals..

Answer (score 2):

Reputation and badges ***may*** slightly influence the first impression of a question or answer. In the end, the actual content wins. Focus on great questions and answers, this will get you far more and better attention.

Comment: Reputation and badges ***may*** _slightly_ influence the first impression

Comment: But will someone take the time to check the origin of a gold medal. A gold medal is a old medal dis-regardless of its stature.

Comment: Maybe not. But, speaking for myself, I would not vote down/up *based* on the user's medals, nor would I track a person's questions or answers based on that. And I don't think too many SO users would.